# How to setup wordpress's htaccess in a sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website hosted on godaddy with the following htaccess configuration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-domains/shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

http://main-domain.com

Then I need to create a sub-domain for our shop and so I created one in this folder: /sub-domains/shop. I also installed another wordpress and woocommerce with permalinks set to hostname.

When I navigate to http://shop.main-domain.com it renders properly, but when I open a page for example: http://shop.main-domain.com/checkout, it redirects back to the http://main-domain.com.

Then I create a htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-domains/shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But nothing happens? Anybody has any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that htaccess is not supported on my Godaddy's windows shared hosting instead I created a Web.config (in the sub-domain's root folder) for IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also in the said hosting php configuration can be overriden by creating another file php5.ini in the root folder of the sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the htaccess file is in your subdomain "shop" folder? Try removing the leading slash in the rule's target:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-domains/shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Still the same error :-(. It redirects to the main website.

Comment: @czetsuya sounds like it could be a wordpress configuration problem and not the rules